# WWDC videos on Mac

Tags: macos, itunes, mac, developer-program

I've downloaded a few of the WWDC videos on my iPad using the [WWDC app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wwdc/id640199958?mt=8). I've also marked some of the videos as favourites.

Can I access these videos on my Mac, maybe from iTunes? I found the videos [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) but there I can't manage favourites and mark as watched/unwatched.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - the same videos that were presented on the iOS app are available as video downloads. All recent WWDC content is posted for anyone to download with no developer account needed:

- https://developer.apple.com/search/index.php?q=wwdc

The 2014 content is available for download in HD/SD and PDF format for almost all the recent sessions. The metadata in terms of stars / favorites and such aren't portable from the iOS app, so you will have to either keep using the iOS device or make playlists in iTunes / use OS X labels and tags and folders  / paper notes of which sessions you want to star / revisit, etc...

According to [Hal Mueller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/719690/hal-mueller) on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/halm/statuses/475444510764589056), if you [run a script to download all the videos](https://github.com/ohoachuck/wwdc-downloader), they will take the following amount of disk space for the 2014 year content:

- HD videos: 31.54 GB
- SD videos: 10.36 GB
- PDF: 0.418 GB

I would note, that you will want to check the history of the script. It currently requires macOS and swift and only downloads the 2016 videos. Older versions might still work with older years, so check the revision history of the shell script version of the tool if you don't want 2016 videos.

Answer (score 0):

You can download these videos using my convenient bash script, here you go: https://gist.github.com/Blackjacx/6f61570e5eea87f977e5af9abb6a76b1

Please leave a comment on Github if you liked it or if you gave any problems with the download. I will fix problems as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Open the appropriate link in Safari, e.g.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/220/

Then select the "Resources" tab. The download links are then available.
[image]

Answer (score -3):

The only way to see these videos it's via Safari.
And you can download each Videos there.
I don't think there is a way to manage your videos as the WWDC app available for iOS.
Maybe there must exists a program where you could manage them.
But for that, you must search.
If i was you, i would download them and put on a file with all the videos and if you see one you could change the name and star it.
Example : Name of a video : "blablabla.mpeg" (Before)
  "*blablabla" (after)

I know that this is not the best solution, otherwise you could search for an application which will do what you said.

Sorry, about the lack of my answer.

Comment: Do you have a link to it?

Comment: @Oskar Developers can download the actual episodes - see my answer...

Comment: That's what i said ... See my answer too ... When i posted my message yours wasn't their ...